# Can I delete CGI*****-* files in /tmp dir

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, tmp

We have a bunch of different applications running on a web server and some of them started falling over; Quickly checking disk space we realised the tmp folder on a seperate partition had become full - Looking through there's lots and lots of CGI*****-* files, where '*' is a number and the last '*' are 2 or 3.

I realise files in the temp directory aren't gaurenteed any permanent life so I *could* just delete them, but I wanted to check first - before I cause even more trouble :-p

I suspect they're related to Ruby on Rails and file uploads.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be safe to remove anything in /tmp that is not currently in use, though to be safe I would leave anything less than a day or so old just in case. If you were to reboot this would probably happen automatically, as most modern distributions clear out /tmp (except very recent files) on startup.

You could set a cron job to delete files that are not recent from /tmp periodically, though it would be advisable to confirm where the files are coming from and try stop this happening again in future rather than just treating the symptom.